# bash: getopts: parse two options with arguments

Tags: bash, getopts

I am trying to parse two options which both need an argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "a:b:" opt; do
    case $opt in
    a)
        echo "a has the argument $OPTARG."
        shift
        ;;
    b)
        echo "b has the argument $OPTARG."
        shift
        ;;
    esac
done
```

What I expect is that this script prints out the arguments of a and b. But the output is only:

```
$ sh ./cmd_parse_test.sh -a foo -b bar
a has the argument foo.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't shift in the loop; use `shift $(($OPTIND-1))` after the loop to leave `"$@"` containing the non-option arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to `shift` to get the next argument. Simply dump whatever you want, and continue for the next iteration, as in:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "a:b:" opt; do
    case $opt in
    a)
        echo "a has the argument $OPTARG."
        ;;
    b)
        echo "b has the argument $OPTARG."
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Which outputs:

```
$ ./cmd_parse_test.sh -a foo -b bar
a has the argument foo.
b has the argument bar.
```

Notice also that you don't have to run the script with `sh`, since you've already set the *shbang* to use `bash`.